# Inferring type from generic

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

Is there any way to infer the type of the object O as in the example below (which will not compile):

```
public interface LogUpdateListener<S extends LogSet<O>> {
    void logUpdated(O object);
}
```

So in the example above `LogSet` is generic taking an `O` where `O extends LogObject`. If `S extends LogSet`, then using `S` is it possible to infer the type of `O` to use as the type for the `logUpdated` method?

Is the only way to do this explicitly like this:

```
public interface LogUpdateListener<O extends LogObject, S extends LogSet<O>>
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood your question, but if you are asking:

1. How do I declare a `LogUpdateListener` ...
2. of type `S` which extends "`LogSet` of type `O`", ...
3. where type `O` extends `LogObject`?

then, yes, you declare it as:

```
public interface LogUpdateListener<O extends LogObject, S extends LogSet<O>>
```

This is because if `O` is a type parameter (which is what I think you are saying), then you need to declare it in the type parameter section. If you also want to bound `O` to be of a subtype of `LogObject`, you need to add that bound along with the type parameter declaration.

However, you should remember that:

- for a type `P` where `P` is a [proper subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) of `O` (`P < O`)
- `LogSet<P>` **is not** a subtype of `LogSet<O>`

This may mean you need to use wildcard parameterized types of `LogSet<? extends O>` or `LogSet<? super O>` in your method declarations if, for example, you wanted to copy from/to (in that order) other `LogSet` objects.

Comment: So there is no way for the compiler to infer `O`'s type without the two generic parameters (which will successfully enforce the desired condition).

Comment: @flungo. Yes, I was just editing to say exactly that. If `O` is a type parameter (which is what I think you are saying) and it is not declared through a parent type (i.e. `LogUpdateListener` is not a nested interface within a parent type which declares the type parameter `O`) then you need to declare it in the type parameter section. All type parameters must be declared in a type parameter section somewhere in scope.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I feel you are right and that there isn't a way of having the definition of O inferred. I am just trying to wrap my head around the the mathematics of why this would not be possible, and if it were what the pitfalls would be.

Comment: @flungo. It's due to the difference between a *type parameter* and a *type argument*. When you use `O` in `LogSet<O>` it is actually a *type argument*, not a *type parameter*. All *type parameters* must be declared; this is a compiler constraint. Therefore you need to declare `O` as a *type parameter* separately in order to use it as a *type argument* in `LogSet<O>`